# How to implement data streaming with the Snap framework?

Tags: haskell, streaming, haskell-snap-framework

I'd like to implement streaming of large data (in both directions) with the Snap server. To explore the possibilities I created a sample program that has two endpoints - reading and writing. There is a very simple internal buffer that holds one `ByteString` and whatever is written to the writing endpoint appears in the reading one. (Currently there is no way how to terminate the stream, but that's fine for this purpose.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}                                           
import Control.Applicative                                                   
import Control.Concurrent.MVar.Lifted                                        
import Control.Monad                                                         
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)                                          
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder (Builder, fromByteString)                    
import Data.Enumerator                                                       
import qualified Data.Enumerator.List as E                                   
import Data.Enumerator.Binary (enumFile, iterHandle)                         
import Snap.Core                                                             
import Snap.Http.Server                                                      

main :: IO ()                                                                
main = do                                                                    
  buf <- newEmptyMVar                                                        
  quickHttpServe (site buf)                                                  

site :: MVar ByteString -> Snap ()                                           
site buf =                                                                   
    route [ ("read", modifyResponse (setBufferingMode False                  
                                     . setResponseBody (fromBuf buf)))       
          , ("write", runRequestBody (toBuf buf))                            
          ]                                                                  

fromBuf :: MVar ByteString -> Enumerator Builder IO a                        
fromBuf buf = E.repeatM (liftM fromByteString $ takeMVar buf)                

toBuf :: MVar ByteString -> Iteratee ByteString IO ()                        
toBuf buf = E.mapM_ (putMVar buf)
```

Then I run in different terminals

```sh
curl http://localhost:8000/read >/dev/nul
```

and

```sh
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 | \
  curl --data-binary @- http://localhost:8000/write
```

But the writing part fails with *an exception escaped to toplevel: Too many bytes read*. This is obviously an instance of `TooManyBytesReadException`, but I couldn't find where it's thrown. Writing smaller amount of data like 1MB works as expected.

My questions are:

1. Where/how to fix the reading limit?
2. Will this stream data, without loading the whole POST request in memory? If not, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you add any content type that's not `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` to your `/write`, e.g.:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 | \
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @- http://localhost:8000/write
```

[This bit](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-server/blob/0.9-stable/src/Snap/Internal/Http/Server.hs#L602) in Snap does something like

```
if contentType == Just "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then readData maximumPOSTBodySize
  where
    maximumPOSTBodySize = 10*1024*1024
```

and `x-www-form-urlencoded` is curl's default.

Comment: Probably `application/octet-stream` would be a more appropriate content type.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on the previous answer: because forms of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` are so common, as a convenience Snap auto-decodes them for you and puts them into a parameters map in the request. The idea is similar in spirit to e.g. `$_POST` from PHP.

However, since these maps are read into RAM, naively decoding unbounded amounts of this data would allow an attacker to trivially DoS a server by sending it arbitrary amounts of this input until heap exhaustion. For this reason `snap-server` limits the amount of data it is willing to read in this way.